# Transfer Data between Two Views : Context Binding

Tags: routes, sapui5

I'm facing a Problem im my SApui5 App, I wanna pass data between views and I'm getting oEvent.getBindingContext() = undefined, I dont know why this is happenning, could you please help me to solve this problem.

My code is below:  (FirstViewController.js)

```
    sap.ui.define([
    'jquery.sap.global',
    'sap/m/MessageToast',
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
    'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'

],

function(jQuery, MessageToast, Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("umicoreMP.controller.FirstView", {

        onInit: function() {
            this.myModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(this.myModel, "data");
            this.getView().setModel(this.myModel, "data");


        },

        onCreate: function(oEvent) {

            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Item Criado", {
                duration: 3000
            });

            // Set busy indicator during view binding

            var oData = {

                mp: {
                    matDesc: this.oView.byId("idMatDesc").getValue(),
                    qtd: this.oView.byId("idQtd").getValue(),
                    um: this.oView.byId("idUm").getValue(),
                    utilizacao: this.oView.byId("idUtilizacao").getValue(),
                    setor: this.oView.byId("idSetor").getValue(),
                    dataFixInicio: this.oView.byId("idDtFixIni").getValue(),
                    dataFixFim: this.oView.byId("idDtFixFim").getValue()
                }
            };

            this.myModel.setData(oData);

            var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
            var oContext = oSource.getBindingContext("data");//undefined
            var oPath = oSource.getBindingContext("data").getPath(); 

            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.navTo("third", oContext, false);

        }
    });

});
```

View.xml Code

```
    <mvc:View xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="umicoreMP.controller.FirstView">
        <Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                <sap.ui.layout.form:SimpleForm xmlns:sap.ui.layout.form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" id="form1" columnsM="2" labelMinWidth="100" singleContainerFullSize="false" width="100%" columnsL="2">
                    <sap.ui.layout.form:content xmlns:sap.ui.layout.form="sap.ui.layout.form">
                        <sap.ui.core:Title xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core" text="Adicionar Item" id="__title1" emphasized="true" icon="sap-icon://sales-order-item" level="H1"/>
                        <Label text="Descrição Material" id="lbMatTxt" busy="false"/>
                        <Input width="80%" id="idMatDesc" maxLength="60" fieldWidth="" valueLiveUpdate="true" value="{/mp/matDesc}" description="{/mp/matDesc}"/>
                        <Label text="Quantidade" width="90%" id="lbQuantidade"/>
                        <Input width="30%" id="idQtd" maxLength="10" value="{/mp/qtd}" description="{/mp/qtd}" valueLiveUpdate = "true"/>
                        <Label text="UM" id="lbUM"/>
                        <Input width="20%" id="idUm" maxLength="3" maxSuggestionWidth="10px" fieldWidth="10%" dateFormat=""  value="{/mp/um}" description="{/mp/um}" valueLiveUpdate = "true"/>
                        <Label text="Utilização" width="90%" id="__label1"/>
                        <Input width="80%" id="idUtilizacao"  value="{/mp/utilizacao}" description="{/mp/utilizacao}" valueLiveUpdate = "true"/>
                        <Label text="Setor" width="90%" id="__label2"/>
                        <Input width="70%" id="idSetor"  value="{/mp/setor}" description="{/mp/setor}" valueLiveUpdate = "true"/>
                        <Label text="Data Fixing Inicio" width="90%" id="__label5"/>
                        <DatePicker width="60%" secondaryCalendarType="Gregorian" id="idDtFixIni"  value="{/mp/dataFixInicio}"/>
                        <Label text="Data Fixing Fim" width="100%" id="__label7"/>
                        <DatePicker width="60%" secondaryCalendarType="Gregorian" id="idDtFixFim"  value="{/mp/dataFixFim}"/>
                        <Label text="Observações" width="100%" id="__label8"/>
                        <TextArea wrapping="None" id="idObs" value="{Obs}"/>
                        <Label text="Label" width="100%" id="__label6"/>
                        <Label text="Label" width="100%" id="__label0"/>
                        <Label text="Label" width="100%" id="__label4"/>
                        <Label text="Label" width="100%" id="__label3"/></sap.ui.layout.form:content>
                </sap.ui.layout.form:SimpleForm>
            </content>
        <footer>
            <Bar id="__bar0">
                <contentRight>
                    <Button text="Proxima etapa" width="150px" id="__button2" icon="sap-icon://arrow-right" type="Emphasized" press="onNextStep"/>
                    <Button text="Adicionar Item" width="150px" id="__button4" icon="sap-icon://add" press="onCreate"/>
                </contentRight>
            </Bar>
        </footer>
        <headerContent>
            <Button width="100px" id="carrinho" icon="sap-icon://cart"/>
        </headerContent>
        </Page>
```

Component.js is:

```
     sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
"sap/ui/Device",
"umicoreMP/model/models"
    ], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
"use strict";

return UIComponent.extend("umicoreMP.Component", {

    metadata: {
        manifest: "json"
    },

    /**
     * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
     * @public
     * @override
     */
    init: function() {
        // call the base component's init function
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        // set the device model
        this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");

        // create the views based on the url/hash
        this.getRouter().initialize();
    }
});

    });
```

my Routing config is:

```
            "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "umicoreMP.view",
            "controlId": "app",
            "controlAggregation": "pages"
        },
        "routes": [{
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "first",
            "target": "first"
        }, {
            "pattern": "secondview",
            "name": "second",
            "target": "second"
        }, {
            "pattern": "thirdview",
            "name": "third",
            "target": "third"

        }],
        "targets": {
            "first": {
                "viewName": "FirstView"
            },
            "second": {
                "viewName": "SecondView"
            },
            "third": {
                "viewName": "ThirdView"
            }
        }

    }
```

Thanks by suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
var oContext = oSource.getBindingContext("data");//undefined
```

The source of the event is the button with the id "__button4". The button itself does not have any binding, unlinke your input fields (or some list items you have seen in examples), so can not get any binding context from it.

If  you want to give your button a context, you can add a binding to it by using custom data. You can see a brief example [here](http://blog.acorel.nl/2015/02/two-very-useful-xml-namespaces-in.html).

However, I suggest to think about to just pass the oData variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
oSource.getBindingContext();
```

'oSource' will give you button instance, and further you are trying to get binding of that, which obviously you have not set, so it is returning as undefined.

To pass data between views do this:

```
 oRouter.navTo("third", oData, false);
```